How come my backend control panel (cPanel) icon appears on password auto-fill selector......?
I've just upgraded my FF browser to v133, and encountered a strange fenomenon that I believe has something to do with my server configuration:

I have no idea if it is somehow related with a similar icon file like "favicon" or maybe .htaccess missing configuration?
At the moment I am on a shared webhost, so I cannot really access the whole Apache configuration, but I know can use .htaccess to alter the default configuration (had I knew what causing cPanel icon to be visible in the password autocomplete selector).
My .htaccess content for reference:
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all


order deny,allow
deny from all

#AuthName efsdk.com

Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /home/efsdkcom/err/notfound.htm
ErrorDocument 500 /home/efsdkcom/err/servererr.htm
ErrorDocument 401 /home/efsdkcom/err/private.htm
ErrorDocument 403 /home/efsdkcom/err/private.htm

# Force SSL on all site
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# Force www for non https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://efsdk.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://efsdk.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.efsdk.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.efsdk.com$      [NC]
#RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|pdf|svg|webp|ttf|mp3|mp4|wav)$ - [F,NC]
AddType application/efon ef

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “alt-php81” package as the default “PHP” programming language.

  AddHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php81___lsphp .php .php8 .phtml

# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

Any help will be appreciated.

Try deleting the cache for your browser, or using its Private/Incognito mode. Check to see if you have your own favicon (instead of cPanel's) in your root directory and is linked to in your source code. See this and this for more.

After trying what @dan (in comment) suggested, I made some checks, and it is really a matter of "favicon.ico" to be located in the right place. Before, I assumed that any name (even SVG icon) while works fine in the page head and bookmark, seems not working well elsewhere.
Seems "favicon.ico" at the moment is a "must" for an icon to work in a proper way, and must be one not only in my script and HTML page folder, but also in the root directory ("home/mydoman/public_html")
